# Show an iPhone in Keynote

Tags: iphone, iwork-keynote, demo

I was wondering if anyone knew if you could, and if so how to show the iPhone in a Keynote presentation to demo software on it? Kinda like they do at the Apple Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there is an easier way to do it, but if all else fails you could use the iPhone Simulator to help out. Depending on how detailed the presentation is you could probably even use screenshots of the simulator so you can throw them onto your slides.

Comment: Yea that was what I was thinking but I thought it might be more impressive to do it within the presentation like they do at the events... Can't find much online about it though!

Comment: I've put this as the answer as it's the best approach to the situation. Hopefully in the future Keynote might include this feature!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a jailbroken iPhone (please don't hit me!) and install a VNC server on it. You can now use a VNC client on your PC using USB or WiFi to show the iPhone screen!

Theres a little tool that lets to establish TCP connections to your iPhone through an USB port:

> http://code.google.com/p/iphonetunnel-usbmuxconnectbyport/

I found these instructions:

1. Launch iPhone_tunnel, forward remote port 22 as local port 2022 (or 22 on Windows):

   ```
   ./iPhone_tunnel
   ```
2. Connect in terminal:

   ```
   ssh root@localhost -p 2022
   ```

Replace port 22 with the VNC port, 5900. Also instead of SSH launch the VNC client :)

Comment: Sounds like quite a good idea actually. Might try that out for my next demo. My latest effort was to use the TVOutManager (https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager) and just switch to it by unplugging the video input to the projector from my laptop to my iDevice!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use the iPhone Simulator and Quicktime to record what you want to show on the Keynote, and then add the video to the slide (assuming you want to show the same actions every time you play the Keynote). Other than that, I would suggest exiting the Keynote and using the iPhone Simulator, then starting the Keynote again (inelegant but it works).

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but this sounds like it might be just what you're looking for:

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/09/16/free-iphone-keynote-and-powerpoint-templates-help-get-you-from-t/

Here's the description frow www.TUAW.com:

---

Free iPhone Keynote and PowerPoint templates help get you from thought to finish
by Sang Tang (RSS feed) on Sep 16th 2009 at 9:00PM

[image]

Mockapp.com has created both Keynote and PowerPoint templates of iPhone UI elements, and has made them available as free downloads. Say you had a dream in the middle of the night about the most awesome iPhone app that, to your surprise, no one has thought of yet. Instead of waking up in a deep sweat and scribbling said ideas on paper, you could dream them up on Keynote.

After mapping out your concept on Keynote, you could then pitch it to others in a Keynote presentation. The Keynote and PowerPoint templates include alerts, the iPhone keyboard, arrow icons, buttons, as well as a host of other UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very late but you should look into SimFinger.
https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger

I use it to simulate a real environment in the simulator (imagine that). I record the demo, and play it in keynote. This should hopefully solve the issue.